# Objective-C Lion Fullscreen use all monitors

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, fullscreen

We have 4 monitors on a wall for graphing. Looking to put them all into use in fullscreen mode. Right now if I do it it just uses one. Just looking to see if it is possible to create an app that allows me to use all 4 with like a simple uiwebview for each monitor.

Should of mentioned this.. Looking for a simple code sample of how to do this or pointers on where to get answers.

Comment: I'm looking for a objective-c example or where to look to do it. So it sort of is

Comment: Sorry, jumped the gun - Mea Culpa

Comment: my fault for not making the question more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Standard Lion fullscreen mode allows for one "primary window", which is sized to take up the entire main screen, and as many "auxiliary windows" (inspector panels, etc.) as you want, which are not automatically sized in any way.

Go into Xcode, create a simple project, and edit the xib. For the existing window, go to the Attributes Inspector and make sure that Full Screen is set to "Primary Window". Now in the object browser, drag three Panels into the app. Go through them and make sure each one has "Utility Panel" for Style, "Auxiliary Window" for Full Screen, and either "Inferred Behavior" or "Transient Behavior" for Exposé. Now, when the first window goes into full screen mode (e.g., when you get the appropriate notification or NSWindowDelegate method), size and move the other three windows to take over the other three screens.

This is all documented pretty well in the [Implementing the Full-Screen Experience](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html) section of the "Mac App Programming Guide" in the 10.7 Core Library.

Comment: Just be aware that you'll have to manage the full-screen transition manually to make your three panels take up a screen apiece (and, if you want them to, to lose their borders, etc.). But if you read the docs, then do a bit of trial&error with the delegate messages, it's not hard.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to put a web view on each screen, it may be easier to use `-[NSView enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:]`.  This isn't Lion's new full-screen mode, it's the earlier technique.  It has different behavior in terms of whether the app is in a separate space, etc.

Comment: Good point. And I believe with the right combination of presentation options on this call and collection behaviors on the window you can even fake Lion fullscreen pretty well, a trick a few web browsers have used (although whether that's a feature or a way to cruelly confuse your users is another question…).